# XSL to count xml node under inside loop

Tags: xml, xslt

## I have my xml as below and I want get the count of title node I have tried below but I always get count as 1 since it is under for-each loop

```
    <xsl:if test="$countryVal !='' and $countryVal = 'USA'">
<tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <h3>Count of titles <xsl:value-of select="count(catalog/cd/title)"/></h3>
    </tr>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>

<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>USD</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>USD</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>CAD</title>
    <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
    <country>CAN</country>
    <company>RCA</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1982</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>USD</title>
    <artist>Gary Moore</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Virgin records</company>
    <price>10.20</price>
    <year>1990</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

#

xml shared is part of big xml sharing the snippet of it.
Any pointers?

Comment: Are you looking for the number of `<title>` nodes in each `<cd>`, or the number in the whole `<catalog>`, or something else? If you're looking for the number in the whole catalog, you don't need the `<xsl:foreach>`; the count will check for all of the results below the `<catalog>` node.

Comment: I'm looking for count of title node under CD only for US countries.

Comment: If that is the case, you can just do `<xsl:value-of select="count(catalog/cd[country='USA']/title)"/>`, but this statement would need to go after the `xsl:for-each`, and not inside it.  Note that you could also simplify your `xsl:for-each` to just `<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd[country='USA']">` and avoid the need for a variable and if condition inside it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use a variable to hold the filtered node-set - so that you only need to apply the filtering once:

```
<xsl:variable name="eligible-cds" select="/catalog/cd[country='USA']" />
```

Then you can do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$eligible-cds">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
<h3>Count of titles <xsl:value-of select="count($eligible-cds)"/></h3>
```

Comment: Thank you that helped but I'm looking for based on my count result inside loop I need to show table data for example if count of title's node is more than one then I need to display only one title since in my case title has same value due to which title values are getting duplicated. I have updated xml my expected xsl logic is something like below

Comment: Ty that helped but based on my count result inside loop I need to show table data for example if count of title's node is more than one then I need to display only one title since in my case title has same value due to which title values are getting duplicated. updated xml     Expected     <xsl:if test="$countryVal !='' and $countryVal = 'USA' and count(title) < 2">
<tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <h3>Count of titles <xsl:value-of select="count(catalog/cd/title)"/></h3>
    </tr>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your comments. Please edit your question and provide an example where the proposed method would not provide the expected output. -- Note that you cannot count within `xsl:for-each`, because it is not a loop.

Comment: I have scenario where I have to get count result inside for-each loop. If count() would not give the desire result then how do we get the count xml node inside for-each loop. Any other functions or pointers? Sample xml is my first post.