# XSL inside for-each logic on count less than 2

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Sample xml from the big xml:

```
<result type="FLP" id="FL">
    <PPR>
        <PP>
            <FID id="L1001">18084</FID>
            <FNAME id="L1002">some text </FNAME>
            <PRM_KEY id="L1349">Yes</PRM_KEY>
            <CURRENCY_CODE id="L1821">CAD</CURRENCY_CODE>
        </PP>
        <PP>
            <FID id="L1001">18084</FID>
            <FNAME id="L1002">some text </FNAME>
            <PRM_KEY id="L1349">No</PRM_KEY>
            <CURRENCY_CODE id="L1821">CAD</CURRENCY_CODE>
        </PP>
        <PP>
            <FID id="L1001">18084</FID>
            <FNAME id="L1002">some text </FNAME>
            <PRM_KEY id="L1349">Yes</PRM_KEY>
            <CURRENCY_CODE id="L1821">USD</CURRENCY_CODE>
        </PP>
        <PP>
            <FID id="L1001">18084</FID>
            <FNAME id="L1002">some text </FNAME>
            <PRM_KEY id="L1349">No</PRM_KEY>
            <CURRENCY_CODE id="L1821">CAD</CURRENCY_CODE>
        </PP>
        <PP>
            <FID id="L1001">18084</FID>
            <FNAME id="L1002">some text </FNAME>
            <PRM_KEY id="L1349">Yes</PRM_KEY>
            <CURRENCY_CODE id="L1821">EUR</CURRENCY_CODE>
        </PP>
    </result>
```

I want to display only FNAME value under my table td when PRM_KEY is Yes but FNAME values are displaying three times since there is no condition for CURRENCY_CODE. I want to display FNAME only once when PRM_KEY is Yes.
I tried below xsl condition but that did not help since count value was always one

```
    <xsl:for-each select="/result[@type='FLP']/PPR/PP[PRM_KEY = 'Yes'] and count(CURRENCY_CODE) < 2">
    <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="FNAME"/></td>
<h4>count val is: <xsl:value-of select="count(CURRENCY_CODE)"/></h4>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Your explanation of the logic that needs to be applied here is not clear.

Comment: I need to show some data based on count() result inside for-each loop not outside the loop since inside the loop I have other condition to satisfy and get the count of xml node.

Comment: As [I already told you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43819695/xsl-to-count-xml-node-under-inside-loop/43820089?noredirect=1#comment74694193_43820089), you cannot count "*inside for-each loop*" because `xsl:for-each` is not a loop. Tell us **what** you're trying to accomplish, not **how** you think it needs to be accomplished.

Comment: In above shared xml, I want to display FNAME only once irrespective of different CURRENCY_CODE and it should display when PRM_KEY is Yes. How do we achieve this result ?

Comment: @user3669116 - It would help if you edited your question, and showed the exact output you want for the given input XML. Thank you!

Comment: @user3669116 I am afraid that's not at all clear. You have 5 records and 3 of them satisfy  PRM_KEY = "Yes". Why would FNAME be displayed only once - and which record should the displayed value come from?

Comment: that's right out of 5 3 of them satisfy PRM_KEY. I have requirement for PRM_KEY is Yes then it's FNAME should display since all FNAME values are same so it should display only once. Is that clear ?

Comment: @user3669116 No, it is not clear. We don't know that all FNAME values are same. It could be just a coincidence, or laziness on your part. You need to specify **exactly** what the stylesheet should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "records" (items) you are interested in are `PP` tags with `PRM_KEY = 'Yes'`.

Then you want to divide them into groups with equal `FNAME`.

For each of the above groups you want to display:

- the `FNAME` (equal for all items in the group),
- how many items (in this group) have defined `CURRENCY_CODE`.

Below you have an XSLT script performing this task:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="ppItems" match="PP[PRM_KEY = 'Yes']" use="FNAME"/>

  <xsl:template match="result[@type='FLP']/PPR">
    <table>
      <xsl:for-each select="PP[generate-id() = generate-id(key('ppItems', FNAME)[1])]">
        <xsl:variable name="kk" select="key('ppItems', FNAME)"/>
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="FNAME"/></td>
          <td>Count: <xsl:value-of select="count($kk/CURRENCY_CODE)"/></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

In order to keep proper structure of HTML, I changed your `h4` tag
into another `td`.

Answer (score 1):

> I have requirement for PRM_KEY is Yes then it's FNAME should display
>   since all FNAME values are same so it should display only once.

If I take your requirement literally, then it should be sufficient to display the first FNAME value when at least one `PP` satisfies the condition of `PRM_KEY='Yes'`. This can be done very simply, without using `xsl:for-each` at all:

```
<xsl:template match="/result">
    <xsl:if test="PPR/PP[PRM_KEY='Yes']">
        <output>
            <xsl:value-of select="PPR/PP[1]/FNAME" />
        </output>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

---

OTOH, it's possible you want to display each **distinct** `FNAME` value - in which case your question is about *grouping* and you can find the answer [here](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).